# NHibernate restriction Count of child collection

Tags: nhibernate, collections, count

Take for example: a Person that has a collection of Pets. I want to only list the Persons that have at least 5 pets.

I have tried:

```
 var result = (from a in UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.QueryOver<Person>()
                          where a.Pets.Count >4
                          select a
                ).List()
```

But it says it does not recognize the property Count (which makes sense because it is not a DB field). I also tried Count() and it still doesn't work saying it doesn't understand that function (throws exception).

I've tried all kinds of subqueries and criteria methods but I don't know enough to put it all together. And I don't know whether I shold use LINQ or HQL or QueryOver or Criteria...It would be much much mch easier in SQL but I don't want to "cheat"

I have been searching google like crazy, and everything I found either does not compile or I get a runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `QueryOver` instead of LINQ (`Query<T>()` extension method)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That was it. I also needed to include the following namespace: 
using NHibernate.Linq;